# Why does Plymouth boot in fallback text mode?

Tags: 11.04, startup, shutdown, plymouth

When starting my system, Plymouth doesn't show graphics but uses the fallback text mode. However, it runs normally (that is, with graphics) on shutdown. Why is that?

Comment: I am also having the same problem, but my shutdown shows randomly text / graphics. VGA: Intel 4500MHD.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it seems to be a bug. I have just reported it in launchpad. It seems to have been accepted as one. [Bug id 781479](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/plymouth/+bug/781479) . If any of you are affected please click on the 'it affects me' to report it.

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) and run the next command.

```
sudo update-initramfs -c -k all
```

You may be asked for you user password, this command recreates the initial ramdisk for all kernels.

Comment: You're aware what `-k all` does, right? It's generally not necessary and can be omitted to safe time as it will update the current loaded kernel by default. I doubt if this solves the problem, I've had a similar issue, the startup plymouth screen is completely blue with only the upperleft corner of the screen being used. On shutdown, it showed up fine. I think it's a kernel module issue as the only difference between my maverick initrd and natty initrd is the kernel.

Comment: I had the SAME issue and this command fixed it .

Comment: @Alaukik: have you installed new drivers then?

Comment: @Lekensteyn my issue is already fixed and no i have not installed newer drivers .

Comment: @Ubuntuser have you tried this ?

Comment: @Alukik: I have tried every solution mentioned here,nothing seems to work for  me. I get the text mode while booting up and get the plymouth graphics while shutting down. its so annoying!!