# Installed fglrx. Plymouth using text theme

Tags: boot, startup, fglrx, plymouth

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Enabling Nvidia driver messes up splash screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6033/enabling-nvidia-driver-messes-up-splash-screen)

My boot splash screen was fine with the open source drivers. I installed fglrx, rebooted, and it seems plymouth is using the ubuntu text theme.

This seems to be my problemL [Why does Plymouth boot in fallback text mode?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40307/why-does-plymouth-boot-in-fallback-text-mode)

However, both my boot and shutdown use the text theme. I tried

```
sudo update-initramfs -c -k all
```

with no luck :-/

Comment: Consider this closed. I found this http://askubuntu.com/questions/6033/enabling-nvidia-driver-messes-up-splash-screen and installing v86d seems to have fixed it.

Comment: Let me remind you this is not a *forum* it is a Q6A site and that there is a flag button below your question , there you can request a mod to close your question.